# What cartoon is this nighttime image of cats from?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I can't provide any more information but the only thing I have is this image:

[image: 2 angulared cartoon cats look over a mole-like creature at nighttime]

Comment: Have you actually seen this or have you just found an image and want to know what it’s from to watch it? Where did you find the image? If you actually have seen it can you remember any of the plot? How old it would be? Etc. If you remember anything by else please [edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: Does the presence of cats in capes make this on-topic? Alas, no.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my question, wasn't sure how to post this. My friend showed the picture to me, and he has no information either, we only have this picture and we know that it's a cartoon. we'd very much like to find which cartoon it belongs to and watch it.